# Как хранить структуру серии писем в БД и инициировать их отправку?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mongodb

Всем привет!))
Вопрос к знатокам)
У нас есть drag'n'drop конструктор цепочки писем.

Мы выбираем письмо1, затем указываем, Письмо 2 и в настройках этого письма пишем когда его нужно отправить. Затем если письмо прочитал сотрудник, отправить Письмо 3А, если письмо не прочитано, отправить Письмо 3Б.

Для наглядности прикладываю скрин:
[image: подпись]

Сразу скажу, что длина цепочки писем может быть хоть какой.

Собственно вопрос, как хранить это все дело в базе и инициировать событие на отправку писем.

Comment: а почему вы указываете mysql и mongodb одновременно. вам какое решение то нужно, для реляционной БД или для noSQL. А так то с виду все просто в таблице писем делаем поле id-родительского письма и признак прочитал/не-прочитал (или NULL). Отдельно можем хранить ожидающие события. в виде id-сотрудника, id-отосланного письма, дата когда проверять. когда дата наступила, делаем проверку прочитал/нет и выбираем из бд письмо где родитель текущее письмо и соответствующий признак

Comment: Спасибо за ответ @Mike Я просто указал варианты БД)) А так, хотелось узнать, может кто-то реализовывал уже такую вещь и может подсказать лучший вариант для хранения данных))